# How to use factory to resolve interface using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, factory

I want to have a service like the following

```
public SomeService(IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase) {
    DB = mongoDatabase;
}
```

and I want to use a factory to resolve `IMongoDatabase`, just to encapsulate the `IConfiguration` usage

```
public static IMongoDatabase GetMongoDatabase(IConfiguration config)
{
    var connectionString = config.Get("SomeConnectionString");
    // MongoClient handles connection pooling internally
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString); 
    var db = client.GetDatabase(config.Get("SomeDbName"));

    return db;
}
```

I can't figure out how to handle the registrations so that `MongoDbFactory.GetMongoDatabase` gets called whenever any class needs an `IMongoDatabase`. `IConfiguration` will be registered already.

I'd really like to just use an `IMongoDatabase` and not a `Func<IConfiguration, IMongoDatabase>` in my Service.  The latter just seems way too obtuse, requiring consumers to implement steps that I should be able to implement for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register your static `GetMongoDatabase` factory method like this :

```
builder.Register(c => MongoDbFactory.GetMongoDatabase(c.Resolve<IConfiguration>)())
       .As<IMongoDatabase>();
```

By the way, using a static method may introduce some problem, it may be better to register the `MongoDbFactory` class and use it in your *factory* registration.

```
builder.RegisterType<MongoDbFactory>()
       .AsSelf();

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MongoDbFactory>().GetMongoDatabase())
       .As<IMongoDatabase>();
```

Of course, you will need to adapt the `MongoDbFactory` implementation to make it work - by adding a property for Configuration and adding IConfiguration to the constructor.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.